# Refresh the classic record page after record created in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-events, quickaction

I have created a Quick action of type VF page, Where it is calling Lightning Component APP. This Lightning component APP is calling LWC.  Whenever a record gets saved, then i need to refresh the whole record page. But it is refreshing the Lightning component only. Here is the sample code what i have tried.
Quick action is using this VF page :

```html
      <apex:page StandardController="ServiceAppointment" showHeader="false">
        <apex:includeLightning />
        <div id="LcDisplayId"></div> 
        <script>
         $Lightning.use("c:LightningComponentAPP", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:LWCComponent", 
                                       { "recordId" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}"}, 
                                       "LcDisplayId", 
                                       function(component) {
                                       });
        });
        </script>
    </apex:page>
```

And Lightning App:

```html
     <aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
          <aura:dependency resource="c:LWCComponent" />
        </aura:application>
```

This is the LWCComponent.html button:

```html
    <div slot="footer" class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-align--absolute-center">
    <lightning-button label="Save" slot="actions" variant="brand" disabled={disableInput}
      onclick={createRecord}>
    </lightning-button>
  </div>
```

This is the lwc.JS action method.

```js
    createRecord() {
         this.isLoading = true;
            updaterecord({ value1: this.input1, acc1: this.acc1, seracc: this.seracc}).then(result => {
                     if (result === 'Success') {
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        //eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();"); //This is what i tried, but did not work
                         location.reload(); //If i am using this the component is reloading. But i need whole record page needs to be refreshed which is in classic and lightning.
    
                    }
    
            }).catch(error => {
                this.isLoading = true;
                console.log('Error occured while processing - ' + error);
                });
            }
    }
```

Can someone please provide any inputs. This will be more helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the top-level window to refresh the entire area:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

Comment: hI @sfdcfox, Thanks for your response. But this did not work. Even not refreshing the current component as well. When am using  location.reload(); it is refreshing the component level.